# Joomla! 2.5 -- Adding a custom field to menu-item-edit-form

Tags: joomla, forms, plugin

I would like to add a new field (select list of all menu-items) to the menu item-edit form. To do so I was setting up an system plugin with the following directory structure:

- [languageroot.php](http://pastebin.com/J5YAqt2p)
- [form.xml](http://pastebin.com/Z1jnRMN2)

As you can see in the posted code, that is all very basic to try out.

Only after adding the following lines:

```
    <li>
    <?php echo $this->form->getLabel( 'langroot-text', 'main' )?>
    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('langroot-text', 'main' ); ?>
    </li>
```

to: `/admininstrator/components/com_menus/views/item/tmpl/edit.php`

a textfield shows up.

Is it possible to inject the field without touching the `edit.php`? Is there anywhere a good tutorial about the JForm API? Is a system-plugin the right kind, or could it be a content plugin, or should it even be a component?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line:

```
<fields name="main">
```

in your XML file to:

```
<fields name="params">
```

This way the plugin system knows that it needs to add this form in the `params` section of the admin interface.